# Convert UTC date to actual date and time

Tags: javascript, ajax, utc

I have a chart of bitcoin prices.  I have the correct prices on the Y-axis, but I cannot get the correct time on the X-axis.  The time shows up in a UTC format in my console.  I am adding price and date to the series each iteration. I need to get the date of that particular result and find the YEAR, MONTH and DAY of that so I can put it in the right format.  Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
              var result = JSON.parse(result);
              series = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                tempArray = [parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
                tempDate = Date.parse(result[i]['date']); 
                series.push(tempDate);
                series.push(tempArray);
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Date object has UTC methods available for you to get the month, day and year from it.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(result[i]['date'],10)),
month = date.getUTCMonth(),
day = date.getUTCDate(),
year = date.getUTCFullYear();
```

Comment: Thanks, my x-axis is still showing Jan 1,1970 and increasing by every other day

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse returns you a Number that represents milliseconds elapsed since 01/01/1970.
You can use it to create a new Date object :

```
...
var ms = Date.parse(result[i]['date'])
var date = new Date(ms)
var year = Date.getFullYear();
...
```

And use date methods like Date.getFullYear() or Date.getMonth(), etc. to build a String

Comment: when I use any of those functions the x-axis still starts at Jan. 1, 1970

Comment: Are you sure result[i]['date'] returns a value that can be parsed ?

Comment: Maybe chart expects a different value type. Check type of var tempDate

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript date object has several methods which you can use to give you the date:

tmpMonth = tempDate.getMonth() +1;

d = tempDate.getFullYear() + "-" + tmpMonth + "-" + tmpDate.getDate();

The getMonth() method will need to be incremented by 1.